# React-Slick - transform: translate3d - Not working on smaller resolutions

Tags: css, transform, react-slick, translate3d

I am using next.js and fetching data via API to slides. React-slick works great until the first break point on lower resolution (890px in this example).

`.slick-track` class has a property that is causing this problem.

```
.slick-track {transform: translate3d((wrong calc here)px, 0px, 0px)}
```

So instead 0px on first value inside translate 3d I'm getting value that is width of element where the list of slides should be shown. And List is moved to right so it cant bee seen.

After click on next button, list is coming to its normal place, but skipping first element in list...

Screenshot: [image]

I have tried to overwrite this property inside module.css via :global and inside base CSS file, but it is still applied. I i put !important at end of my property it will be applied but I wont be able to scroll/navigate through elements of slide (first element will be stuck to left).

I also have tried older versions of react-slick 26.0; 26.1; 27.0; 28.0... But problem is still here.
Does anyone has some idea for solution?

Here is my component:

```
const Accessories = () => {
  const { query } = useRegions();

  const { error, data } = useAccessoriesSubcategoriesQuery({
    variables: { ...query },
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error("Accessories section component error", error.message);
  }

  const subcategoryItems = data?.categories.edges[0].node.children.edges || [];

  // Slick slider settings
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    nextArrow: <AccessoriesNextBtn currentSlide={0} slideCount={0} />,
    prevArrow: <AccessoriesPrevBtn currentSlide={0} slideCount={0} />,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 890,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 620,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 420,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div className={"flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full bg-white"}>
      <Container className="flex-col relative overflow-hidden">
        <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row w-full mb-[50px] gap-[30px] lg:gap-[20px] justify-between">
          <H2Headline className="text-[26px] text-left ">
            Pool equipment & water treatment
          </H2Headline>
          <Button
            className={`${styles.accessoriesSeeAllBtn} mb-[50px] mr-[0px] ml-auto xs:mb-0 xs:ml-0 xs:mr-auto max-w-[112px] h-[45px] box-border text-solidGray font-semibold text-[16px] leading-[157%] bg-white border border-solidGray hover:bg-solidGray hover:text-white`}
          >
            {/* <LinkBuilder linkItem={data?.categories.edges[0].node}>See all</LinkBuilder> */}
            See All
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.accessoriesSliderWrapper} md:min-w-[500px] w-full`}>
          <style jsx global>{`
            .slick-track {
              display: block;
              transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
            }
          `}</style>
          <Slider {...settings}>
            {subcategoryItems.map((item) => (
              <div
                key={item?.node.id}
                className="flex flex-col max-w-[366px] md:max-w-[263px] transform hover:-translate-y-3 duration-500 ease-in-out "
              >
                {item.node.backgroundImage ? (
                  <div className="flex justify-center items-center content-center h-[280px] bg-lightGray rounded-[12px] overflow-visible z-50">
                    <Image
                      src={item.node.backgroundImage?.url}
                      width={218}
                      height={218}
                      alt="Category image"
                      className="object-cover object-center w-auto h-auto"
                      placeholder="blur"
                      blurDataURL={item.node.backgroundImage?.url}
                    />
                  </div>
                ) : null}
                <h3 className="text-solidGray text-[16px] leading-[160%] font-medium mt-[12px] mb-[3px]">
                  {item.node.name}
                </h3>
                <ParagraphText className="text-[14px] text-gray opacity-100 mt-[3px] mb-[12px]">
                  {item.node.description}
                </ParagraphText>
                <Button className="mx-auto text-[14px] border border-lightGray bg-white w-full hover:bg-solidGray hover:border-solidGray hover:text-white">
                  <LinkBuilder linkItem={item}>See all</LinkBuilder>
                </Button>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Slider>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and in my case change "display: flex" for track and list helped

```
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
    display: flex !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem I ended up using a timeout function in onInit to add the proper `translate3d(0, 0, 0)`:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images (or links to images) of code. Anything text-based (code) should be posted directly into the answer and [formatted properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). By posting images we are not able to copy your code to reproduce it. Also, it is not searchable so others can find your answer easily. For more, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because slider is rendering with empty array.

just wrap with a condition before Slider element to check if array length is greater than 0.

```
  {subcategoryItems.length>0 && <Slider {...settings}>
   ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using ref

```
const sliderRef = useRef()

 useEffect(() => {
      if (sliderRef.current) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          sliderRef.current.slickGoTo(0)
        }, 0)
      }
    }, [optionsType]) 

<Slider ref={sliderRef} {...settings}>{...slides}</Slider>
```

optionsType is a constant i use to know   what options i need to show